# Firebird Entity Framework casts all string parameters to Varchar(8191)

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, firebird, database-first

I'm using VS2017 and Firebird as database. I use database first to create my Model from all stored procedures. When I execute a procedure, all string variables cast as `CAST(@I_NAME AS VARCHAR(8191))` and when I have more than 5-6 string variable I get this error:

```
SQL error code = -204
Implementation limit exceeded
block size exceeds implementation restriction.
```

Why it does not get the size which is defined in the stored procedure in Firebird (for example `varchar(20)`)?

I there any way to prevent casting here? Or any other idea to sole this problem.

Comment: IIRC, the problem is that in Firebird parameters are - by default - described by their target, and you can't have longer lengths, which can be problematic for `SIMILAR TO` clauses, or usage of parameters where there isn't a target type. To circumvent that, the provider adds those casts. I'm not sure if there is a way to disable that or to enforce lower limits.